# Can a failed Clojure agent be restarted automatically?

Tags: clojure

I'm trying to understand whether a failed agent can be automatically restarted. It doesn't appear so from my code example:

```
(def a (agent 0))

(defn h [a e]
  (restart-agent a 0))

(set-error-handler! a h)

(send a inc) 
;; 1

(send a #(/ % 0)) 
;; error handler h will be triggered

(send a inc) 
;; ArithmeticException Divide by zero (agent didn't restart)
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing is, at the point where you call `restart-agent` no restart is necessary. You can show this by changing your handler to this:

```
(defn h [a e]
  (try (restart-agent a 0)
    (catch Exception e (println e))))
```

An exception is thrown saying ‘Agent does not need a restart’. Only after the handler has run does it `:fail` (or `:continue`).

Don’t know what you’re after, perhaps introduce a pacemaker?

```
(def a (agent 0))
(def a-pacemaker (agent nil))

(defn h [a e]
  (send a-pacemaker (fn [_] (restart-agent a 0))))

(set-error-handler! a h)
```

Comment: I'm marking this as the correct answer as it helped me to understand the actual cause of the problem, which meant I thus understood why @AlanThompson's answer (i.e. using a future) worked.

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be an undocumented requirement that `restart-agent` be called in a different thread than the error handler:

```
(dotest
  (future (println "running in a thread..."))
  (let [agt (agent 0)

        ; This doesn't work
        h01 (fn [a e]
              (println :10 "agent error found:" )
              (println :11 "restarting agent...")
              (restart-agent a 100)
              (Thread/sleep 100)
              (println :12 "agent restarted, state=" @a))

        ; This works. Need to call restart-agent in a separate thread
        h02 (fn [a e]
              (println :20 "agent error found:" )
              (future
                (println :21 "restarting agent...")
                (restart-agent a 200)
                (println :22 "agent restarted, state=" @a))) ;=> 200
  ]
    (set-error-handler! agt h02)
    (send agt inc)
    (Thread/sleep 100) (spy :01 @agt)  ;=> 1
    (Thread/sleep 100) (send agt #(/ % 0))
    (Thread/sleep 100) (spy :02 @agt)  ;=> 200
    (Thread/sleep 100) (send agt inc)
    (Thread/sleep 100) (spy :03 @agt)  ;=> 201
))
```

With results:

```
running in a thread...
:01 => 1
:20 agent error found:
:21 restarting agent...
:22 agent restarted, state= 200
:02 => 200
:03 => 201
```